# How to hide sent messages in the omnet++ animation?

Tags: c++, omnet++

I defined a number of messages in .msg file.

For example:

```
message Test{
...
}
```

I want the Test messages sent between submodules to be hidden in the omnet++ animation.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Open `File` | `Preferences...` from the menu of the started simulation, and then choose `Animation` and uncheck `Animate Messages`.

Reference: section "8.7.3. Configuring Animation" of [OMNeT++ User Guide](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/UserGuide.pdf).

Comment: Can you give an example according to my assumptions?

Comment: I write `className(Test)` in field of _Messages to exclude from animation_ of the tab _Filtering_, but Test messages are not hidden.